# Stripping text content in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a little tricky problem.

I have:

```
<span contenteditable="true" onblur="alert(this.textContent)">
     some initial content
</span>
```

Now I copy text from MS Word. It has a lot of xslt formatting.

In Safari and Chrone all the xslt/xml is stripped, but in FireFox it remains fully formattet instead of stripping the text out.

Anyone who knows how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this.textContent.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');